# How do i keep my input fields in the same place regardless of the error message being displayed or not?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am developing a form which has certain error message when there is an error in the form. My problem is when ever the error message is displayed my form inputs are displayed as i wanted. This is the image which shows the display i want (this is with the error display property being commented out. It was display:none) [image: This is the design i want regardless of error message being displayed or not. Meaning i want the input fields to be in the same place as this picture]

But when the display property(display:none) is active the input fields tend to shift their position like this [image: Input fields being displayed like this which i dont want]

What should i change in the code to make sure that my text input fields should look somehow like this. [image: I want my fields to look like this whenever there is no error message showing]

How do i achieve this.

My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Intro component with sign up form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Learn to code by watching others</h1>
    </header>

    <article class="first-para">
      <p class="main-paragraph"> See how experienced developers solve <span class="second-line">problems in real-time.
          Watching</span>
        <span class="third-line">scripted tutorials is great, but</span> understanding how developers think is
        <span class="invaluable">invaluable.</span></p>
    </article>

    <section class="try-box">
      <p><span class="try">Try it free 7 days</span> then <br /> $20/mo. thereafter</p>
    </section>

    <form class="claim-form" action="/">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="first-name">
      <img class='error-img' src="/images/icon-error.svg" alt="error">
      <div class="err err-first">First Name cannot be empty</div>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="last-name">
      <img class='error-img' src="/images/icon-error.svg" alt="error">
      <div class="err err-last">Last Name cannot be empty</div>

      <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email">
      <img class='error-img' src="/images/icon-error.svg" alt="error">
      <div class="err err-email">Looks like this is not an email</div>

      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
      <img class='error-img' src="/images/icon-error.svg" alt="error">
      <div class="err err-pass">Password cannot be empty</div>

      <button class="claim-btn">CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</button>
      <p class="agree">By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <span class="terms">Terms and
          Services</span></p>
    </form>
  </section>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('css-reset.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

:root {
    --color-red: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
    --color-green: hsl(154, 59%, 51%);
    --color-blue: hsl(248, 32%, 49%);
    --color-dark-blue: hsl(249, 10%, 26%);
    --color-grayish-blue: hsl(246, 25%, 77%);
    --color-white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --font-weight-four: 400;
    --font-weight-five: 500;
    --font-weight-six: 600;
    --font-weight-seven: 700;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins',
        sans-serif;
    background: url('/images/bg-intro-mobile.png') var(--color-red);
}

.container {
    max-width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

header h1 {
    color: var(--color-white);
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-six);
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding: 50px 50px 20px 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.first-para {
    max-width: 17rem;
}

.main-paragraph {
    color: var(--color-white);
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-four);
    font-size: 0.85em;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    line-height: 2;
}

.second-line {
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.third-line {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.invaluable {
    margin-left: 92px;
}

.try-box {
    width: 270px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: var(--color-blue);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: var(--color-white);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
}

.try-box p:not(.try) {
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-four);
}

.try {
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-six);
}


.claim-form {
    width: 270px;
    background-color: var(--color-white);
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#first-name,
#last-name,
#email,
#password {
    width: 240px;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 13px 0 0px 15px;
}

.error-img {
    /* display: none; */
    position: relative;
    left: 220px;
    bottom: 24px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

.err {
    /* display: none; */
    color: var(--color-red);
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.err::placeholder {
    color: var(--color-dark-blue);
    /* opacity for firefox */
    opacity: 70%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-seven);
}

.claim-btn {
    width: 240px;
    margin: 13px 0 13px 15px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: var(--color-white);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px;
    background-color: var(--color-green);
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-four);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.claim-btn:active {
    opacity: 50%;
}

.agree {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    color: var(--color-grayish-blue);
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.terms {
    color: var(--color-red);
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-six);
    margin-left: 65px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is a bit unclear. It appears you don't want help with the actual form, but rather the height of the form wrapper when the errors are not present - as in there is too much space below the *terms and services* text/link.

Comment: Yes @disinfor i wanted help when the errorrs are not present. I dont want the input fields to shift the position and have the same margin top/bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `display: none;`, which removes elements from the document, you can use `visibility: hidden`.  Setting the [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) hides the element without changing the layout of a document.  Another option that would work similarly, would be `opacity: 0`.

Both of these options are fine for sighted users, but you should also set `aria-hidden` to `true` when they are not visible to avoid the errors being read by screen readers.

Comment: Thank you @jme11 . This property helped me clear the confusion and achieve the result i wanted.